# Javascript redirect looping only on IE8

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-8

I doing a simple redirect to force users to use HTTPS instead of HTTP.  I know there are plenty of ways of shortening the newUrl variable, however it's the fact that this loops in IE8 continously but works in FF.  The rest of the page does not even load.... but I get the desired URL in which i am hoping for.... Does anyone know why window.location operates differently on IE8??

```
<script language="JavaScript">
    if (location.protocol = "http:") {
        var newUrl = "https://";
        newUrl += location.hostname;
        newUrl += ":64040";
        newUrl += location.pathname;
        newUrl += location.search;
        // redirect
        window.top.location = newUrl;
    }
</script>
```

Comment: I wonder how this could have worked in any browser.

Comment: https://github.com/SublimeLinter/SublimeLinter

Comment: Constructive comments... putvande!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You must use two = to compare the string:

```
if (location.protocol == "http:") {
```

Comment: ...or arguably *three* equals signs.

Comment: Thanks.... kinda stupid now, but the 2 equals in my if ealier think i keep swapping between != and == and then to above.